# armv7m Linux kernel-4.4.5 hangs at calibrate_delay_converge()

Tags: linux, arm, kernel

I debug kernel-4.4.5 boot via hardware debugger. And it reaches calibrate_delay_converge() function and hangs there forever in the following loop.

ticks = jiffies;
while loop.
while( ticks==jiffies )

```
;
```

ticks = jiffies;

My hardware is stm32f429-disc1. I've used "DTS" file stm32f429-disco.dts but changed one line defining memory. As it is attached to BANK2 I changed address to 0xD0000000. The rest of hardware configuration is left unaltered.

**UPDATE:**

Edited ***stm32_clock_event_set_periodic()*** from "drivers/clocksource/timer-stm32.c". Hardcoded 500000 instead of ***data->periodic_top***. And managed to reach end of kernel initialization.

So it looks like

***data->periodic_top = DIV_ROUND_CLOSEST(rate, prescaler * HZ); ***

in timer initialization code gives wrong value. But I can't check it as the value itself is optimized out.

Is it a kernel bug?

Answer (score 0):

On my experience, when I had such kind of crashes, normally is because there are no interrupts in the system. I suggest you to place a BP in the IRQ handler..